# Glass BSDF gets totally grey/white in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, glass

I have a little problem here:

As you can see I am using a Glass BDF in cycles. At the left you can see my cycles render output and at the left you can see my The viewport shading output. I would want it so i can see trough the glass into the box, but that wont work (even if IOR = 0). Could someone please help me?

greetings,
Sjondepon

[image]

Comment: The render output is the sphere icon on the right side, not the middle.

Comment: I am aware of that, but that's not my question

Comment: It's not a raytraced render as the cycles. Of course you won't see the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cycles, for a glass material you need to set the roughness to 0 and the IOR to 1.450 on a glass BSDF. For the viewport shading, it is not possible to make the glass transparent unless you switch to eevee rendering engine and adjust the materials (You'll have to learn about screen space reflections).

Edit: For more transparency:

With only glass shader:[image]

With transparent and glass shader:[image]

Comment: So i will never be able to use glass in cycles?

Comment: @Sjondepon I am saying that glass works properly in cycles with an IOR of 1.450 but it doesn't work in eevee (or viewport shading) until unless you use some tricks. Glass works in cycles, I repeat.

Comment: oh i see, thank you! but is there a way to see more details in my object behind the glass?

Comment: @Sjondepon Yes there is. If setting the IOR to 1.450 and the roughness to 0 doesn't help, you can drop a mix shader between the glass shader and the material output and then cnnect a transparent shader to the bottom socket of the mix shader. This will make your material a bit more transparent. I will add an image in my question of the material setup.

Comment: @Sjondepon You can check the question now, I've attached examples.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! (: